# Google App Engine: IN filter and argument position

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have a table where one of the columns contains a list. I want to know if it is possible to select all rows where the list contains a specific element.

More concretely, I have a `guests` column containing a list of strings and I want to know if a specific `guest` string is part of this list. I would like to write a query like this:

```
q = TableName.gql('WHERE :g IN guests', g=guest)
```

It seems, however, that I can't put variables in this position. For instance, this query (where ownerid is a string and not a string list) is also disallowed:

```
q = TableName.gql('WHERE :g = ownerid', g=guest)
```

I seem to have to write it this way:

```
q = TableName.gql('WHERE ownerid = :g', g=guest)
```

Thus I have the following questions:

1. How can I construct a query that gets rows where a list-cell contains a specific member?
2. Are arguments for GQL queries restricted to the right-hand side of operators? What is the restriction?

I am using Google App Engine with Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood what the `IN` operator is for. It is not for querying against a repeated field: you just use the normal `=` for that. `IN` is for querying against a list of *values*: eg `guest IN [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Your query should be:

```
q = TableName.gql('WHERE guests = :g', g=guest)
```

or better, since GQL doesn't give you anything that the standard DB syntax doesn't:

```
q = TableName.all().filter('guests =', guest)
```